# Unkown array of objects appearing in console after sending data to client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to send some data through socket.io. In particular I am sending an array of objects containing values for a card game such as

```
socket.emit('yourCard', deck.filter(x => x.playerId === userIds[i].id));
```

console.log on the server side of this will give me this array, as expected.

```
[
  {
    Value: '4',
    Suit: 'spades',
    id: 3,
    playerId: '-pFddkeoWzdPWZo4AAAB'
  },
  {
    Value: '2',
    Suit: 'diamonds',
    id: 14,
    playerId: '-pFddkeoWzdPWZo4AAAB'
  }
]
```

client side code:

```
socket.on('yourCard',function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
```

but in console on the client browser in firefox, I am seeing this

```
0: Object { Value: "10", Suit: "spades", id: 9, … }
​
1: Object { Value: "J", Suit: "spades", id: 10, … }
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: []
​​
concat: function concat()
​​
constructor: function Array()
​​
copyWithin: function copyWithin()
​​
entries: function entries()
​​
every: function every()
​​
fill: function fill()
​​
filter: function filter()
​​
find: function find()
​​
findIndex: function findIndex()
​​
flat: function flat()
​​
flatMap: function flatMap()
​​
forEach: function forEach()
​​
includes: function includes()
​​
indexOf: function indexOf()
​​
join: function join()
​​
keys: function keys()
​​
lastIndexOf: function lastIndexOf()
​​
length: 0
​​
map: function map()
​​
pop: function pop()
​​
push: function push()
​​
reduce: function reduce()
​​
reduceRight: function reduceRight()
​​
reverse: function reverse()
​​
shift: function shift()
​​
slice: function slice()
​​
some: function some()
​​
sort: function sort()
​​
splice: function splice()
​​
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString()
​​
toSource: function toSource()
​​
toString: function toString()
​​
unshift: function unshift()
​​
values: function values()
​​
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): function values()
​​
Symbol(Symbol.unscopables): Object { copyWithin: true, entries: true, fill: true, … }
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

The first three lines are expected, but my question is 'what are these objects being sent, wiil they affect performance if I will send a package every 40 milliseconds to the client, and can/should I get rid of these objects?' Also, sending a plain string will only return the string in the console.

Any answer to any of the above questions is much appreciated.

Comment: What you are seeing is just an array. Arrays have those properties in their prototype. (After all, you can use `[1, 2, 3].map` for example.)

Comment: Try `console.log([123, 456])` in the console to see what I mean.

Comment: You are correct. This answers my question.